# Google foo-bar challenge Level 3 - Doomsday-fuel - Markov chains

Tags: matrix

I'be been trying to solve the google foo-bar challenges and I'm stuck at level 3 with failing test cases. I applied the Markov chain theory explained there: https://github.com/ivanseed/google-foobar-help/blob/master/challenges/doomsday_fuel/doomsday_fuel.md

My code passes all test cases except for 4,5,6,7. I initially thought it was because of my use of floats to represent fractions. So I spent a few hours on implementing the same solution only using integers in Fraction objects (which takes more time because you have to rewrite matrix operations to work with fractions). But Alas! The same test cases are failing for this solution too.

If only I knew the inputs of those tests!

Here's my first solution using matrices of floats, subsequently converted into fractions:

```py
import numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction

def find_empty_rows(matrix):
    return np.where(~matrix.any(axis=1))[0]

def calculate_row_sums(matrix):
    row_sums = np.sum(matrix, axis=1)
    return row_sums

def convert_values_into_fractions(matrix, row_sums):
    matrix = matrix.astype(float)

    row_sums[row_sums == 0] = 1
    row_sums = row_sums.reshape(-1, 1)

    probability_matrix = matrix / row_sums

    return probability_matrix
    

def extract_submatrix(matrix, row_indices, col_indices):
    submatrix = matrix[np.ix_(row_indices, col_indices)]
    return submatrix


def float_to_fraction(number, precision=1e-10):
    # Find the numerator and denominator using Fraction
    fraction_result = Fraction(number).limit_denominator()

    # Check if the precision is sufficient
    while abs(float(fraction_result) - number) > precision:
        # Increase the denominator for better precision
        fraction_result = Fraction(number).limit_denominator(fraction_result.denominator * 2)

    return fraction_result

vectorized_float_to_fraction = np.vectorize(float_to_fraction)
    
class NonSimplifiedFraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

def normalize_fractions(fraction_matrix, common_denominator):
    result_matrix = np.empty_like(fraction_matrix, dtype=object)

    for row in range(fraction_matrix.shape[0]):
        for col in range(fraction_matrix.shape[1]):
            current_fraction = fraction_matrix[row, col]
            result_matrix[row, col] = NonSimplifiedFraction((current_fraction.numerator * common_denominator) // current_fraction.denominator ,
                                               common_denominator)

    return result_matrix

def solution(matrix):

    m = np.array(matrix)

    empty_rows = find_empty_rows(m)

    if 0 in empty_rows:
        return [1] + [0]*(len(matrix) - 1 ) + [1]

    non_empty_rows = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(m.shape[0]), empty_rows)

    row_sums = calculate_row_sums(m)

    m = convert_values_into_fractions(m, row_sums) #change matrix into fractional floats
    R = extract_submatrix(m, non_empty_rows, empty_rows)
    Q = extract_submatrix(m, non_empty_rows, non_empty_rows)

    I = np.identity(Q.shape[0]) #create identity matrix same size as Q

    IminusQ = I - Q

    F = np.linalg.inv(IminusQ)  #take inverse of matrix

    FR = np.dot(F, R)

    fraction_matrix = vectorized_float_to_fraction(FR)   #convert floats to Fractions

    flattened_fractions = fraction_matrix.flatten()

    denominators = [fraction.denominator for fraction in flattened_fractions]

    common_denominator = np.lcm.reduce(denominators)

    fractions_with_common_denominator = normalize_fractions(fraction_matrix, common_denominator)

    end_array = [fraction.numerator for fraction in fractions_with_common_denominator[0]]
    end_array.append(common_denominator)

    return end_array
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I did this challenge a couple of months back and completed all test cases. From what I remember: this is what I would suggest.

#### Potential Issues and Improvements

1. **Precision and Arithmetic Approach:**

   - Initially, you used floats and then converted these to `Fraction` objects. This approach can introduce floating-point inaccuracies. A better approach is to use `Fraction` from the start for all arithmetic operations. This ensures that you're always dealing with exact arithmetic, which is crucial in problems involving probabilities and matrix operations.
2. **Matrix Operations with Fractions:**

   - When rewriting matrix operations for fractions, it's important to ensure that these operations are handled precisely. The built-in `Fraction` class in Python provides a way to do this, but you need to ensure that all matrix operations (like inversion, multiplication, etc.) are compatible with `Fraction` objects. This might mean implementing these operations manually or using libraries that support fractional arithmetic.
3. **Handling Zero Row Sums:**

   - In your code, you replace zero row sums with one to avoid division by zero. This approach is logical, but it's essential to ensure that this doesn't lead to incorrect probability calculations, especially in edge cases. In Markov chains, rows with all zeros typically represent absorbing states, and this needs to be correctly reflected in your computations.
4. **Matrix Inversion and Multiplication:**

   - You use NumPy's `linalg.inv` for matrix inversion and `dot` for multiplication. While these are efficient, they might not be precise with `Fraction` objects. Consider implementing a custom matrix inversion method that's tailored for fractional arithmetic.
5. **Normalization of Fractions:**

   - Your approach to normalize fractions to a common denominator at the end is good, but ensure that this process doesn't introduce any errors, especially when dealing with very large or small numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

1. As I said, I re-implemented the same algorithm without using floats and I have the same result so it is not a precision issue.
2. I re-implemented those operations manually and they seem to work for me...
3. The reason I change the row_sum to 1 in case of terminal state is just to avoid division by zero when converting the whole matrix to Fraction objects, it will then be Fraction(0, 1). I'm not even using them actually.
4. I re-implemented that also but I didn't test it thoroughly. What type of input could break it?
5. What numbers do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trial and error I found that the problem was the way I calculated the common denominator. Whenever the greatest common divider was greater than 1, the tests would fail.

So I ended up adding the following at the end:

```py
lowest_common_multiple = np.lcm.reduce(denominators)
numerators = (lowest_common_multiple * fraction_matrix[0]).astype(int)
greatest_common_divisor = np.gcd.reduce(numerators)

#adding the sum of numerators to the non-simplified array
numerators = np.append(numerators, numerators.sum())

#then magic happens
end_array = (numerators / greatest_common_divisor).astype(int)

return end_array
```